# How to get rid of "Sort" & "Delete" columns in MDBootstrap React MDBTableEditable component?

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

In [their demo code](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/editable/), they have the following columns listed:

```
const columns = ["Person Name", "Age", "Company Name", "Country", "City"];
```

Yet, "Sort" & "Delete" columns get appended to the right. How to get rid of these to columns?

Comment: Do you have any sample sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I got access to their source code. And they have the columns **HARD CODED**

```
<tr>
    {columns && columns.map((th, i) => {
        return <th key={i}>{th}</th>; })}
    <th>Sort </th>
    <th>Delete </th>
</tr>
```